# To implement realpath(path) in php

Tags: php, html

Is that possible to implement php function realpath(path) for the below code?

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/home.jpg">
```

I am trying this:

```
<?php $homepath = realpath ("assets/images/home.jpg");  ?>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $homepath ?>">
```

but the image doesn't show.

Comment: What do you expect that function to do to an HTML tag??

Comment: I am trying this `<?php $homepath = realpath ("assets/images/home.jpg"); ?> <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $homepath ?>"> `but the image doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

`realpath()` returns the path to a file *on your server's hard disk*. This is likely to be something along the lines of:

```
/home/yourusername/public_html/assets/images/home.jpg
```

Putting this path in an HTML tag will not work. Don't do it.

Comment: Yea I get this in return `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/foldername/assets/images/home.jpg`

Comment: I have a container for menu header of webpage in root.  index.php enable to grab this menu header successfully in display page.  But those submodule in sub folder structure are unable to read that container's path.  Can I have suggestion how to cater this technical issue?